# How to filter TFS contributors to a specific project?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

Currently I can get all of the TFS contributors using `workItemStore.FieldDefinitions[CoreField.AssignedTo].AllowedValues`, but the thing is that I want to search for the allowed members of a specific project(I already have the project info extracted from TFS), as the results are in the hundreds instead of just 5-6.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Not wat you are asking, but usually if people ask this they actually want to list members of the team within a project or a single security group of a project; http://blog.johnsworkshop.net/tfs11-api-query-teams-and-team-members/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get valid user for a specific team project:

```
List<string> displayNames = new List<string>();
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/collectionname"));
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

        WorkItemTypeCollection workItemTypes = workItemStore.Projects["Agile"].WorkItemTypes;

        WorkItemType wiType = workItemTypes["task"];

        var allowedValues = wiType.FieldDefinitions[CoreField.AssignedTo].AllowedValues;

        foreach (String value in allowedValues)
        {
            displayNames.Add(value);
        }
```

However, for your data-binding requirement, could you please offer more information? By the way, what kind of project you're working with? A winform project?

Comment: I have edited my question, so as your answer turned extremely useful, please edit it so it suits fully the question and I will accept it :) Thank you !